# getIntent().getData() == null for unity app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, unity-game-engine, uri

so Im running a java plugin that extends UnityPlayerActivity.  Im successfully overwriting the onCreate function.  Only problem is when I try to get the intent data coming in, its null. The data Im looking for is the url that Triggered the Intent.

```
package com.company.androidlink;

import java.net.URL;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.unity3d.player.*;

public class Main extends UnityPlayerActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
            uri = intent.getData();
            url = new URL(uri.getScheme(), uri.getHost(), uri.getPath());
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.androidlink"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed a plugin some months ago to send a text to a Unity3D app. The method, which is in the root activity (equivalent to your "Main") is the following:

```
public static String getExtraText() {
    String extraText = "";

    // Store extra parameter for later.
    Intent intent = UnityPlayer.currentActivity.getIntent();

    if (intent != null) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();

        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW) && type != null) {
            if (type.equals("text/plain")) {
                extraText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                DebugBridge.log_d("Extra Text: " + extraText);
            } else {
                DebugBridge.toast("Unknown MIME type");
            }
        }
    }

    return extraText;
}
```

I did not get the text at startup, just invoke the "getExtraText" from Unity app when needed (at Start usually).

This is the way I send data from another android native test app to unity:

```
boolean sendMessageToApp(String message, String appName) {
    ComponentName name = findNativeApp(appName);

    if (name != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setComponent(name);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```